# Vertical slice architecture with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

i have a `dotnet new` [template project](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoWebApiStarter) where i'm doing [vertical slice architecture](https://headspring.com/2019/11/05/why-vertical-slice-architecture-is-better/) for the service layer using servicestack.

even though the convention is to use `{hello}.cs` / `{hello}Response.cs` / `{hello}Service.cs`,

everything in my project is called `Request.cs` / `Response.cs` / `Service.cs` because they live inside their own namespaces.

things are working fine but now everything on the `/meta` page is indistinguishable from each-other except for the endpoint urls.

is there anyway i can get around this? is there some kind of attribute in servicestack that i can decorate each of my request, response DTOs and the service classes with; so that they populate the service discovery/ meta pages appropriately?

if nothing like that exists, how would i go about achieving my requirement? could the behavior of servicestack be modified by creating a plugin or something?

cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's [metadata page](https://docs.servicestack.net/metadata-page) isn't customizable, but you should easily be able to create your own customized view that's displayed how you like. The metadata ServiceStack has about your Services is available from `IAppHost.Metadata` API which returns a populated [ServiceMetadata](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/ServiceMetadata.cs) object graph.

If you enable [#Script Pages](https://sharpscript.net/docs/script-pages) you can register the collection as a **global** variable:

```
Plugins.Add(new SharpPagesFeature {
    Args = {
        {"meta", HostContext.Metadata},
    }
});
```

Then in a custom page like `/metaview.html` you can group, sort and order the services as you like, e.g. here's an example of [grouping](https://sharpscript.net/linq/grouping-operators) available operations by namespace and displaying a link to each operations JSON metadata page:

```
{{ meta.Operations |> groupBy => it.RequestType.Namespace |> to => namespaces }}
{{#each namespaces}}
<b>{{it.Key}}</b>
<ul>{{#each it}}<li><a href="/json/metadata?op={{it.Name}}">{{it.Name}}</a></li>{{/each}}</ul>
{{/each}}
```

This `meta` collection is available in your [Debug Inspector](https://docs.servicestack.net/debugging#debug-inspector) which gives you an interactive playground with instant feedback on how you want your Services displayed which you can paste into your [/metadata/debug page](https://sharpscript.net/metadata/debug) to view the output:

[image]

This allows you to quickly experiment with the layout, e.g. if you just want to show your own and none of ServiceStack Services you can filter it like:

```
{{ meta.Operations |> groupBy => it.RequestType.Namespace |> to => namespaces }}
{{#each namespaces where !it.Key.startsWith('ServiceStack') }}
<b>{{it.Key}}</b>
<ul>{{#each it}}<li><a href="/json/metadata?op={{it.Name}}">{{it.Name}}</a></li>{{/each}}</ul>
{{/each}}
```

If you're new to [#Script](https://sharpscript.net/) I recommend going through [#Script's interactive LINQ Examples](https://sharpscript.net/linq/restriction-operators) to learn about it in practice.

Of course you can also use [ServiceStack.Razor](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-razor) if that's your preference which you can access in your Razor `.cshtml` pages from the `HostContext.Metadata` singleton.

Comment: this is awesome. thank you very much for the detailed answer. btw, you're doing a marvelous job with servicestack. i am really impressed with it. i will be purchasing a license in a couple of months. bravo!!!